# PHP mySql large data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get data from a table which having million of records in it. My query is based on some other tables also which cause many joins. Now once we execute this query its hang the database and taking too much time to execute and during this time all other operations with the database stop working.

Can anyone help me what is the best way to handle such type of queries?

Regards

Comment: Do you have proper indicies?

Comment: show us the queries and the db schema, impossible to answer otherwise

Comment: Try running your query preceeded by "describe" to see how the indices are used and where you might fix them.

Comment: select C.name,round(sum(sessiontime)/60,0) as minutes,round(sum(sessionbill),0) as BillAmount from zz_cc_call as A left join cc_card as B on A.card_id=B.id
Left Join cc_card_group as C on B.id_group=C.id left join cc_agent as D on C.id_agent=D.id
where D.login='$UNAME'

Comment: above is example of query

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo_mysql) as your MySQL driver, try this class (namespace it or rename it to avoid conflicts, as needed):

```
<?php
class MySQL {

    private $result;

    /**
     * Constructor establishes a database connection via PDO.
     */
    public function __construct($host, $port, $dbname, $username, $password, $sql) {
        try {
            $db = new PDO(
                sprintf( "mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s", $host, $port, $dbname ),
                $username,
                $password,
                array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
            );
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false));
            $this->result = $db->query($stmt);

        } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
            sprintf("MySQL Connection Error: %s", $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Next Table Row
     *
     * @return stdClass Get next table row as a stdObject.
     */
    public function next_row() {
        return $this->result->fetchObject();
    }

}
```

The constructor accepts all of your database variables needed to establish a connection, as well as the $sql string for your query. The option `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false` should keep your query from timing out by not loading all of the results into memory at once.

Example usage:

```
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "3306"
$dbname = "mydatabase"
$username = "user"
$password = "l33th@ck3r"
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo='bar'";
$mysql = new MySQL($host, $port, $dbname, $username, $password, $sql);

while ($row = $mysql->next_row()) {
    // do stuff here
}
```